# Query array of arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document in a mongodb collection which represents a Snort rule parsed with the perl Parse::Snort library:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5328b974be4ed1400900000a"),
"dst_port" : "6000",
"opts" : [ 
    [ 
        "msg", 
        "\"X11 xopen\""
    ], 
    [ 
        "flow", 
        "established"
    ], 
    [ 
        "content", 
        "\"l|00 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00|\""
    ], 
    [ 
        "fast_pattern", 
        "only"
    ], 
    [ 
        "metadata", 
        "ruleset community"
    ], 
    [ 
        "classtype", 
        "unknown"
    ], 
    [ 
        "sid", 
        "1226"
    ], 
    [ 
        "rev", 
        "10"
    ], 
    [ 
        "gid", 
        "1"
    ]
],
"proto" : "tcp",
"direction" : "->",
"src" : "$EXTERNAL_NET",
"update" : "0",
"action" : "alert",
"dst" : "$HOME_NET",
"src_port" : "any"
}
```

I am trying to search all documents in this collection with opts.sid=1226,opts.gid=1 and opts.rev=10.

With the following line I am able to find all documents with sid=1226:

> db.rules.find({"opts":{"$elemMatch":{"$all":["sid","1226"]}}});

But I can't figure out how to search filtering more fields such as ["gid","1"] and ["rev","10"]  
Does anyone know how I can add the extra conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$all` directly on the `opts` field to do this:

```js
db.rules.find({opts: {$all: [['sid', '1226'], ['gid', '1'], ['rev', '10']]}})
```